# Como guardar imagenes en una carpeta usando php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, imagen

Estoy usando una base de datos en phpmyadmin para realizar un ejercicio de clase, en el que tengo que crear una clase para insertar contenido de un formulario y se crearía el post, yo consigo guardar en la base de datos el contenido del formulario, pero la imagen que inserto, se guarda solo como el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos, por lo tanto necesito que al guardar en nombre en la base de datos también guarde el archivo de la imagen en una carpeta llamada blog, situada donde tengo mi proyecto, he estado buscando tutoriales pero no logro saber que estoy haciendo mal, dejo por aquí mi trozo de código para insertar imágenes.

```
    <?php
    
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "bd";
    //Crear conexion 
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    //Comprobar conexion.
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MYSQL" .
        mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $nombreImg = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "blog/" . $nombreImg;
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $slug = $_POST['slug'];
    $abstract = $_POST['abstract'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $imagen = $_POST['image'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($ruta, $destino)) {


        $sql = " INSERT INTO bd(post_title,post_slug,post_abstract,
    post_body,post_date,post_image,nombre,ruta) VALUES ('$titulo','$slug','$abstract',
     '$body','$data','$imagen','$nombreImg','$destino') ";


        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

            die('Error:' . mysqli_error($con) . "<br>SQL:=" . $sql);
        }

        echo "registro añadido correctamente";
    }
}

    
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo cambiando tu funcion `copy()` por `move_uploaded_file()` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $nombreImg = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $ruta      = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destino   = "/blog/" . $nombreImg;
    
    if (move_uploaded_file($ruta, $destino))
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'bd'(nombre,ruta) VALUES ('$nombreImg','$destino')";
        $res = mysqli_query($cn, $sql);
        if ($res) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Agregado Correctamente"); window.location="index.php";</script>';
        } else {
            die("Error" . mysqli_error($cn));
        }
    }
}
```

En la documentación de esa función en php puedes inclusive ver un ejemplo práctico y muy simple de la carga de una imagen.

Referencia: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me he dado cuenta que el código debia colocarlo en otro archivo que guarda lo que se le inserta, no debia estar en el formulario de inserción, he probado a colocar en el nuevo fichero todo pero ahora tampoco me sube el articulo(el post)  la web, ya no se guarda.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de "copy" prueba usar "move_uploaded_file":

```
...
 if(move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino)){
...
```

Ver un ejemplo completo https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp